# Navbar menu items vertically centered

Tags: css

I'd like my green menu items to be centered vertically in the red container (which has a 70px height).
I've been able to achieve this by playing with the margins but this is not an ideal solution. What would be the "cleanest" way to achieve this no matter what the red container height is?
Many thanks,

[image]

```
.nav-wrap {
  width:100%;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
    z-index:10;
    opacity: 0.9;
    left: 0; 
    margin-top: 0; 
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari et Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */

        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the idea of how to complete your assignment.

```css
nav{  
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  
    background: #ff0000;
}
nav > div{
    height: 70px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
}
nav > div > label{
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2.5px 5px;
    background: green;
  
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div><label>Who are We</label></div>
  <div> <label>Services</label></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```
.green-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
}
.green-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```